# Search Enginein VB

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys i am a rookie programmer i am trying to build a Search Engine in VB with MySQL as the back end. The database is not that large just a few concepts stored but in the form of images,text,PDF .

Now i have managed to connect to my database  but i don't know what to code to get the search results like Google. 
For e.g. if i  search  selecting text format i should get the results in paragraphs and if its images then results should be the images stored in my database. can anyone help me with the code because i don't know where to start

Comment: Don't roll your own, just use [Lucene.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.net/)

Comment: if the DB includes something like an attribute indicating whether each item is Img, Txt, PDF, MP4 etc, it is a matter of a WHERE clause in the search SQL, `.Filter` or something similar depending on HOW you are displaying the data returned.  Show some code or we dont know where to start.

Comment: I need the txt result in textboxes,image results in pictureboxes and PDF results in the form of a list where i can click an individual file name and display it in the PDF reader tool that i have on the form

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did a few years ago :

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices



Module PredicateBuilder
Sub New()
End Sub
Public Function [True](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return Function(f) True
End Function
Public Function [False](Of T)() As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return Function(f) False
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function [Or](Of T)(expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[OrElse](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function [And](Of T)(expr1 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), expr2 As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Dim invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast(Of Expression)())
    Return Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))(Expression.[AndAlso](expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters)
End Function
End Module
```

And I used this class that way :

```
    'POST: /Search
    <HttpPost()>
    Function contactSearch(ByVal search As String, ByVal opportunite As opportunite) As ViewResult

        Dim chaine As String = Request("searchString") 'obtient la chaine introduite par l'user au clavier
        Dim tabMot() = chaine.Split(New Char() {" "c}) 'transforme la chaine en tableau de mots
        Dim distance As Integer
        distance = Request("dist")                      'obtient la valeur introduite par l'user dans la CBbox

        Dim flag As String = "ok"                       'sert à dire à la vue qu'on est passé par  ici, et qu'il peut tenter d'afficher les résultats de la recherche
        Dim n As Integer = 0                            'sert à compter le nombre de contacts récupérés. On introduira cette valeur dans la taille du tableau qui sera créé
        Dim i As Integer = 0                            'sert d'indice dans le tableau dans lequel sont stockées les coordonnées


        'Tout ce bloc sert à construire une liste de contacts répondant aux critères
        Dim predicate As Expression(Of Func(Of contact, Boolean))
        predicate = PredicateBuilder.False(Of contact)()
        For Each mot In tabMot
            Dim tmp = mot
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(m) m.titre.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.departement.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.qualifications.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.langue1.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.langue2.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.langue3.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.langue4.Contains(tmp))
            predicate = predicate.Or(Function(m) m.langue5.Contains(tmp))

        Next
        Dim contacts = db.contact.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList()
```

Hope this helps. (I was using Linq to entities)

Comment: If there's something wrong, or if you dislike my answer, please provide me information instead of putting -1

Comment: sorry about that i am new to stackoverflow i did it by mistake as i mentioned before i am a rookie

Comment: @TheRookie: Don’t worry, you didn’t do it. You need 125 reputation to downvote.